# How to open Dialog Box automatically when app receive notification in background?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-alertdialog, background-process

I want to open DialogBox automatically when app receive firebase push notification(Without clicking on notification). And app is not running . It is closed.
You can find similar functionality in Truecaller(Flash message). One user can send flash message to another user and on 2nd user a full diloag box open with message and notification sound. I need to make same functionality.

I've tried somethings but nothing work.

1. Sending broadcast inside onMessageReceived and receiving it on Activity.
2. Direct call startActivity inside onMessageReceived.
3. Running a service and then calling startActivity.

Answer (score -1):

You can start an activity directly from your onMessageReceived method.
Just don't forget to add Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag to your intent.

```java
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

Comment: You can't start activity from background from API level 29 https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Comment: @MalikBilal ok so can I show DialogBox instead?.

Comment: @Abdul you can get SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW (draw over app) permission for opening activity from the background. Or https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/bubbles

Comment: @MalikBilal I tried this - SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW (draw over app) permission. But it showing popup only when app is running not when app is closed. There must be a way because some app still doing this like truecaller.